# suggestion to my structure activitys (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, structure

I have many common code in onCreate/onPause etc...

I created a CommonActivity that extend Activity and mines activity extend that (oooh fine all work now)

but... now I need a ListActivity (with `setListAdapter`) and all common code of CommonActivity

(obs i use Sherlock action bar, I don't extend directly Activity/ListActivity)
show my problem:

[image: Problem with sctructure]
(sorry by paint mode on!)

how can I do that?

EDITED:
I need ListView to use that (I don't know other way):

```
ArrayAdapter<MyBean> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyBean>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: If you've gone through all that, why do you think you _need_ a `ListActivity`? Have you evaluated how much more effort an `Activity` with a `ListView` would mean?

Comment: i edited, plz show my question now.

Comment: I solve my problem and now i m not utilizing ListActivity

Comment: @rcorbellini well done, then post your solution and accept your hown answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `ListActivity` to use the following code snippet:

```
ArrayAdapter<MyBean> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyBean>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

With a minor modification, the same commands are valid for a `ListView` object, as I already pointed out, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29):

```
ArrayAdapter<MyBean> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyBean>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
setAdapter(adapter);
```